# What is the second component?

Tags: resistors, diodes

[image: Component board]

The second component on the board says Diode CKT. What is that? Doesn't the left handed side of that component look like a resistor?

Comment: Yes, it does look like a resistor. Probably in series with a diode, therefore "Diode Circuit" or CKT.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a resistor(left) and a power diode(right) connected in series to me :)